# How to convert the "root mean squared" to the "standard deviation"?

Tags: statistics

Is there any way of converting the "root mean square" of a set of N measures to the "Standard deviation" of these measures, without knowing the value of N?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have the "root mean square" of a set of values then you need to know the mean value to subtract to get the standard deviation.

If you have the "root mean square" of a set of errors (ie the mean value is zero) then the rms **is** the standard deviation.

In neither case do you need 'n'

Comment: If the mean is non-zero, it cannot just be subtracted from the RMS to get the standard deviation. You would need to compute the standard deviation separately by subtracting the mean from the individual values first.

Comment: I don't think either of you are correct, though Martin is close. The square of the mean needs to be subtracted from the square of the rms to obtain the variance. @niran90 where did you get that the original data is needed? See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square#Relationship_to_other_statistics and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4613151/computing-std-dev-given-rms-and-mean